# Scan directories in groovy with ant builder file scanner

Tags: groovy, antbuilder

I want to use fileScanner of AntBuilder to go over directories.

My code looks like:

```
scanner = new AntBuilder().fileScanner {
    fileset(dir:sourcedir, casesensitive:false) {
        include(name:pattern)
        type(type:'dir')
    }
}
```

I want to loop with the scanner just on directories, for example:

```
for (file in scanner) {
    assert file.directory == true
}
```

Any idea ?
Thanks!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it with `fileScanner`

```
scanner = new AntBuilder().fileScanner {
    fileset(dir:sourcedir, casesensitive:false) {
        include(name:pattern)
    }
}

// Just the directories
scanner.directories().each {
    println it.name
}
```

You could also do it with Groovy calls:

```
def dirs = []
new File( sourcedir ).eachDirRecurse {
    // Check the name here, obviously the Ant pattern you have probably won't work
    if( it.name ==~ pattern ) dirs << it
}

dirs.each {
    println it.name
}
```